# LDAP Manager Attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, webforms, ldap

I'm creating an LDAP class that contains a function that returns the managers username of the current user.

I know that I can use the "manager" attribute to return CN="name", OU="group", DC="company" etc.

I specifically want the managers username, does anyone know if there is an attribute string that I can send to LDAP that specifically gets the managers username only? If not, is there an alternative method to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured out the resolution to this now.

Basically, the `manager` attribute in LDAP retrives the `distinguishedName` attribute of the maanger user.

So if I search LDAP for the user containing the `distinguishedName` that is returned from the manager then I can get any of their attributes that way.

Answer (score 3):

The above GetManager works great except when no manager has been set up. Slight alteration to accommodate this scenario:

```
// return manager for a given user
public UserPrincipal GetManager(PrincipalContext ctx, UserPrincipal user) {
    if (user != null) {
        // get the DirectoryEntry behind the UserPrincipal object
        var dirEntryForUser = user.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;

        if (dirEntryForUser != null) {
            // check to see if we have a manager name - if so, grab it
            if (dirEntryForUser.Properties["manager"] != null && dirEntryForUser.Properties["manager"].Count > 0) {
                string managerDN = dirEntryForUser.Properties["manager"][0].ToString();
                // find the manager UserPrincipal via the managerDN 
                return UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, managerDN);
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution would be to use something like this - this requires that you're on .NET 3.5 and you have referenced both `System.DirectoryServices` as well as `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`:

```
// return manager for a given user
public UserPrincipal GetManager(PrincipalContext ctx, UserPrincipal user)
{
    UserPrincipal result = null;

    if (user != null)
    {
        // get the DirectoryEntry behind the UserPrincipal object
        DirectoryEntry dirEntryForUser = user.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;

        if (dirEntryForUser != null)
        {
             // check to see if we have a manager name - if so, grab it
             if (dirEntryForUser.Properties["manager"] != null)
             {
                 string managerDN = dirEntryForUser.Properties["manager"][0].ToString();

                 // find the manager UserPrincipal via the managerDN 
                 result = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, managerDN);
             }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

And you could then call this method e.g. like this:

```
// Create default domain context
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

// find yourself - you could also search for other users here
UserPrincipal myself = UserPrincipal.Current;

// get the manager for myself
UserPrincipal myManager = GetManager(ctx, myself);
```

Answer (score 0):

Both examples work fine. But I believe there's space for improvements.

Methods should not be checking if parameter is null, and returning null is a bad habit. hrowing exceptions, on the other hand, is more adequate.

Instead of asking for a context it should be possible to retrieve the context from the provided `UserPrincipal`, thus there shouldn't be any problems finding the current user.

```
public static UserPrincipal GetManager(UserPrincipal user)
{
  var userEntry = user.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;
  if (userEntry.Properties["manager"] != null
    && userEntry.Properties["manager"].Count > 0)
  {
    string managerDN = userEntry.Properties["manager"][0].ToString();
    return UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(user.Context,managerDN);
  }
  else
    throw new UserHasNoManagerException();
}

class UserHasNoManagerException : Exception
{ }
```